# How to extract text matching a regex using Vim?

Tags: vim, text, extract, text-extraction

I would like to extract some data from a piece of text with Vim. The input looks like so:

```
72" title="(168,72)" onmouseover="posizione('(168,72)');" onmouseout="posizione('(-,-)');">>
72" title="(180,72)" onmouseover="posizione('(180,72)');" onmouseout="posizione('(-,-)');">>
72" title="(192,72)" onmouseover="posizione('(192,72)');" onmouseout="posizione('(-,-)');">>
72" title="(204,72)" onmouseover="posizione('(204,72)');" onmouseout="posizione('(-,-)');">>
```

The data I need to extract is contained in the `title="(168,72)"` portions of the input. In particular, I am interested in extracting coordinate pairs in parentheses.

I thought about using Vim to first delete everything before `title="`, but I am not really a regex guru, so I am asking you. If anyone has any hint, please let me know! :)

Comment: Like other posted vim use of stream expression is very powerful. These stream manipulator are also available whit sed (almost the same thing whitout the `:%`). If you want to learn more about these expressions have a look at this [sed introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will replace each line with a tab-delimited list of coordinates per line:

```
:%s/.* title="(\(\d\+\),\(\d\+\))".*/\1\t\2
```

Answer (score 4):

This task can be achieved with a much simpler solution and with few keystrokes using normal command:

```
:%normal df(f)D
```

This means:

1. `%` - Run normal command on all file lines;
2. `normal` - run the following commands in normal mode;
3. `df(` - delete everything until you find a parenthesis (parenthesis included);
4. `f)` - move the cursor to );
5. `D` - delete everything until the end of the line.

You can also set a range, for example, run this from line 5 to 10:

```
:5,10normal df(f)D
```

Comment: Interesting way to do this without macros

Comment: normal command is a very powerful tool. It's almost a "one time macro".

Answer (score 3):

If you want an ad hoc solution for this one-off case, it might be quicker simply to select a visual block using <kbd>CTRL-v</kbd>. This will let you select an arbitrary column of text (in your case, the column containing `title="(X,Y)"`), which can then be copied as usual using `y`.

Comment: Yeah a quick no-brain series I find my self using is: `^vGx.......` judging the number of repeats (`.`) visually - pragmatic but works fine 80% of the cases

Answer (score 1):

you can match everything inside title=() and discard everything else like this:

```
:%s,.*title="(\(.*\))".*,\1,
```